# RSS Feed weird characters

Tags: php, rss, special-characters

I am pulling in an RSS feed using PHP. I get weird characters in my feed when the article contains characters like `â€™`.

I have tried `htmlentities` with `ENT_SUBSTITUTE`, `htmlspecialcharacters`, `iconv` and several sanitize functions, none of which ultimately worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use output buffering on the whole page, then use htmlentities() on the content before flushing it.

Where is the data coming from? If it is from a database, are you sure that you set the encoding correctly? I always recommend UTF-8.

Comment: it is coming from an RSS generated by a wordpress blog. `http://dearpaleo.com/?feed=rss2` in this instance.